# Implicit commit in python's sqlite3 when query start with comment

Tags: python, sqlite

I use sqlite3 version 2.6.0 python 2.7.
Why queries starts with comment ('/* */' or '--') cause an implicit commit?

Example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
try:
    os.remove('db1')
except OSError:
    pass

import sqlite3

cur1 = sqlite3.connect('db1').cursor()
cur2 = sqlite3.connect('db1').cursor()

# In first cursor open a transaction
cur1.execute('CREATE TABLE test(t text);')
cur1.execute('BEGIN;')
cur1.execute('INSERT INTO test(t) VALUES (\'123456\');')

# In first cursor first transaction is invisible.
print 'Cursor 1'
print cur1.execute('SELECT * FROM test;').fetchall()

# In second cursor first transaction is invisible.
print 'Cursor 2'
print cur2.execute('SELECT * FROM test;').fetchall()

# In first cursor execute a query, begin with comments.
# Here is implicit commit!
print 'Cursor 1'
print cur1.execute('/* 123 */ SELECT * FROM test;').fetchall()

# In second cursor data now visible!
print 'Cursor 2'
print cur2.execute('SELECT * FROM test;').fetchall()
```

After a query with comment at the begin, cursor cur1 implicitly commits its changes. Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long-standing bug in the Python 2 `sqlite3` bindings. See [issue 10740](http://bugs.python.org/issue10740):

> As evidence of that, note that the existing statement detection code is broken: it doesn't strip comments first!  A simple SELECT statement preceeded by a comment will implicitly commit!

The bindings will implicitly commit before DDL statements, but the way this is implemented it will *also* do so when a line starts with a comment.